# Easier way to read input from a file

Tags: julia

I need to read input from the following input file and initialise all the variables.

**Input File**

```
A=1.0
B=1.0
C=2.0
```

I use following `Julia` code to read this.

```
# Read the delemited file
in = readdlm("inputFile.in",'=');
# Declare all the variables before initialising them with the data from input file.
A=0.0; B=0.0; C=0.0;
# Parsing
for i in 1:length(in[:,1])
  if in[i,1] == "A"
    A=in[i,2]
  elseif in[i,1] == "B"
    B=in[i,2]
  elseif in[i,1] == "C"
    C=in[i,2]
  else
    println(STDERR,in[i,1],"\tKeyword not recognised.")
    exit()
  end
end
```

This method is **not scalable** to large number of input variables. As you will notice, I want to read the variable names and initialise them to the value given in the input file.

Is there a more elegant/short way of doing this? I want to save the names of the variables in an array and use a `for` loop to read them from the file.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe like this?

**Basic approach**

I'm going to read values from file `config.txt` which contains the following

```
A=1.0
B = 2.1
C= 3.3
D =4.4
```

I do not want to hardcode what variables could be there, so I'm going to keep all of them in one Dict, like this:

```
julia> vars = Dict{String, Float64}()
Dict{String,Float64} with 0 entries

julia> f = open("config.txt")
IOStream(<file config.txt>)

julia> for line in eachline(f)
           var, val = split(line, "=")
           vars[strip(var)] = parse(Float64, val)
       end

julia> vars
Dict{String,Float64} with 4 entries:
  "B" => 2.1
  "A" => 1.0
  "C" => 3.3
  "D" => 4.4

julia> vars["A"]
1.0
```

**Reading only some variables**

If you want to limit the set of variables which should be read, it's easy to do as well:

```
julia> vars = Dict{String, Float64}()
Dict{String,Float64} with 0 entries

julia> allowed = ["A", "B", "C"]
3-element Array{String,1}:
 "A"
 "B"
 "C"

julia> f = open("config.txt")
IOStream(<file config.txt>)

julia> for line in eachline(f)
           var, val = split(line, "=")
           stripped = strip(var)
           if stripped in allowed
               vars[stripped] = parse(Float64, val)
           end
       end

julia> vars
Dict{String,Float64} with 3 entries:
  "B" => 2.1
  "A" => 1.0
  "C" => 3.3
```

Now `D=...` from `config.txt` is ignored, as the name was not in `allowed`.

**Having variables as variables, not as Dict**

One more approach would be:

```
function go(;A=0.0, B=0.0, C=0.0)
        println("A = $A, B = $B, C = $C")
end

vars = Dict{Symbol, Float64}()

f = open("config.txt")
allowed = ["A", "B", "C"]

for line in eachline(f)
    var, val = split(line, "=")
    stripped = strip(var)
    if stripped in allowed
        vars[Symbol(stripped)] = parse(Float64, val)
    end
end

go(;vars...)
```

Running this with the same `config.txt` prints

```
A = 1.0, B = 2.1, C = 3.3
```

Comment: Thank you. Looks interesting.

Comment: I'll add one more approach now.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have your variables in a text file in the format you have them then this will work nicely (it just parse/eval's each line).

```
inputfile = readlines("inputFile.in")
eval.(parse.(inputfile))
```

I just realised this doesn't use a for loop, is that a requirement? if so then something like this would also be good:

```
open("inputFile.in", "r") do f
    for line in eachline(f)
        eval(parse(line))
    end
end
```

But if you don't need to save your variables in a text file then the JLD package is the most convenient option & will be much more scale-able.

```
using JLD

A=1.0
B=1.0
C=2.0

@save "myfirstsave.jld" A B C
@load "myfirstsave.jld"
```

Comment: I do not specifically need `for` loop. I will go with your first approach. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If the input file contains Julia code only, you can just include it:

```
include("inputFile.in")

println("A", A)
```

Depending on your workflow, it may be easier than using JLD, since your input file remains a single human-readable text file, rather than a binary file generated by a another text file.

The main con is that you cannot refer to the set of input variables programmatically, e.g. list them, check for existence, etc...